# Flutter app - getting continuous error "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread"

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-admob

Getting continuous error in VSCode debug console like:

> I/Choreographer(16759): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   E/eglCodecCommon(16759): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
>   I/chatty  (16759): uid=10089(u0_a89) RenderThread identical 2 lines
>   E/eglCodecCommon(16759): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
>   I/Choreographer(16759): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   E/eglCodecCommon(16759): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
>   I/chatty  (16759): uid=10089(u0_a89) RenderThread identical 2 lines
>   E/eglCodecCommon(16759): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
>   I/Choreographer(16759): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Just after adding firebase_admob plugin and initializing FirebaseAdmob instance, this error started showing in the debug console like an infinite loop and thus making app slow/hanging.

```
FirebaseAdMob.instance
        .initialize(appId: "ca-app-pub-123457890xxxxxx~1234567890")
        .then((response) {
          print("starting admob >>>>>>>>>");
      myBanner
        ..load()
        ..show(anchorOffset: 0.0, anchorType: AnchorType.bottom);
    });
```

after commenting firebaseadmob initialization, error goes away. My admob version is firebase_admob: 0.6.1

What can I do?

Comment: Hi, have you included your ad_mob AppId in your AndroidManifest.xml as per the setup instructions here: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_admob

Comment: Yes. I have followed the steps and added in correct place in manifest file. I tried Flutter Analyze but no issue found. Also tried Flutter clean still getting continuous error of skipped frame.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, you can wrap the initializeFirebase function to return a value, even though it's not needed in this context. You can modify your code like this:

In your **background_tasks.dart** file, make a slight change to the initializeFirebase function:

> import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core';
>
> Future initializeFirebase(_) async {
> await Firebase.initializeApp();
> }

In your **main.dart** file, call the initializeFirebaseOnBackgroundIsolate function like this:

> import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
> import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart'; // Import the foundation package for >compute
>
> import 'background_tasks.dart'; // Import the background tasks file

> void main() async {
> runApp(const MyApp());
> await initializeFirebaseOnBackgroundIsolate();
> }

> Future initializeFirebaseOnBackgroundIsolate() async {
> await compute(initializeFirebase, null);
> }